# When is the deadline to use the "Keep My Fare" feature on the All Nippon Airways (ANA) website?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, ana

I see there is a deadline to use the "Keep My Fare" feature on All Nippon Airways (ANA) website:

[image]

The screenshot was taken about 1 week prior to the flight departure.

When is the deadline to use the "Keep My Fare" feature on the [All Nippon Airways (ANA) website](https://www.ana.co.jp/en/us/)?

Comment: Downvoted for lack of research effort. It took me well under a minute of browsing the ANA website to find [this page](https://www.ana.co.jp/en/us/plan-book/terms/#anchor-online-booking-benefits), which states the deadline very clearly, and if you didn't find that the first google results page for *ana "keep my fare"* returns several hits which include this information in the excerpts displayed on the google results page, nevermind on the pages themselves.

Comment: @ChrisH 72h in your link is not the deadline but the holding period

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt it talks about both. Moo's answer is correct. A "purchase or reservation deadline for a fare" is distinct from the "keep my fare" holding period.

Comment: @ChrisH "Depending on the purchase or reservation deadline for a fare, there are cases in which the ticket must be issued within 72 hours." -> sounds like it depends on the purchase or reservation deadline for a fare. How can one find the reservation deadline for a fare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Depending on the purchase or reservation deadline for a fare, there are cases in which the ticket must be issued within 72 hours. In this case, the application field will not be shown on the payment screen and the itinerary will not be eligible for this service.

https://www.ana.co.jp/en/jp/book-plan/reservation/international/kmf/

Comment: 72h is not the deadline but the holding period

Comment: How can one find the purchase or reservation deadline for a fare?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt that sounds like another question, worth asking as such because someone might be able to point to something in the fare code or somesuch.

Comment: suddenly the question seems less easy? sounds good I'll ask the obvious implied question that a decent answer would have addressed. -> [How can one find the purchase or reservation deadline for a fare when booking a flight on the All Nippon Airways (ANA) website?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/174685/1810)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt the question asked here was trivial.  The question it subsequently led to is a valid question in its own right.  You’ve been here more than long enough to know that this is a “one question” site, and follow up questions should get asked separately.  You have a follow up question - thats got nothing to do with how trivial this original question is.

Comment: Had I asked the follow-up question first, some people would have complained about the X-Y problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137512/discussion-between-moo-and-franck-dernoncourt).