# How can one find the purchase or reservation deadline for a fare when booking a flight on the All Nippon Airways (ANA) website?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, ana

https://www.ana.co.jp/en/jp/book-plan/reservation/international/kmf/ states:

> Depending on the purchase or reservation deadline for a fare, there are cases in which the ticket must be issued within 72 hours. In this case, the application field will not be shown on the payment screen and the itinerary will not be eligible for this service.

How can one find the purchase or reservation deadline for a fare when booking a flight on the All Nippon Airways (ANA) website?

Comment: I think that applies only when making a booking through a travel agent, not directly on the website.  I know Concur Travel/Amex can do reserve-without-paying but AFAIK access is limited to corporate travel and you need to pay a service fee per booking.

Comment: @lambshaanxy interesting, I was using the feature from the ANA website: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mk9nb.png

Comment: Huh, I did not know that was possible.

Comment: @lambshaanxy Many airlines offer this service, including American Airlines and British Airways. I've also used it on a group ticket on Alaska Airlines.

Comment: @gparyani Yes, I was referring specifically to ANA.